# Webpack: inject text as html within a React Web App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ejs, html-webpack-plugin

**Goal:** I run a website for a small magazine. I'm trying to give each article it's own web page.
To increase search engine optimization, **I want to insert the article text and title as html**, not javascript

---

**My solution so far**

I think I can ~do this with a '.ejs' template using `html-webpack-plugin`. For example

```js
    let articlePlugs = articles.map(function(arr) {
      let [article, articleTitle] = arr
      return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './html/article.ejs',
        inject: true,
        chunks: [iss],
        filename: './articles/' + article + '/index.html',
        templateParameters: {
          article: article,
          articleTitle: articleTitle
        }
      }) 
    })
```

Which will insert the unique article text and article title into the sections marked `<%= article %>` and `<%= articleTitle %>` in my `.ejs` template. After build, I would have my unique html files.

---

**Website Layout**

Currently I use the same outline of a header, a footer, and a background for each webpage, with the unique content nested inside. It looks approximately like this code below

```js
    var Page = () => {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header />
                <div id='bGndImg'>
                   <div id='gradient'>
                        {This is where the unique code goes}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
    
    const root = document.getElementById('content');
    ReactDOM.render (
        <Content />,
        root
    )
```

---

**The problems I need answers to**

Ideally I would insert the article text where the unique content goes, but I feel like this won't be possible.

Another method I thought, might be to have separate executions of `ReactDOM.render` for the header, the footer, and whatever other elements, and set up the html body to look something like

```html
      <body>
        <div id='header'>
            <div id='bGndImg'>
                <div id='gradient'>
                    <div><%= ArticleText %></div>
                    <div id="SomeAdsOrSomething"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id='footer'>
      </body>
```

I don't know if this is possible using webpack though. From what I understand, each html file with webpack can only have one entry point, specified at `config.entry` within `webpack.config.js`

```js
    const config = {
      mode: 'development',     
      entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
        contact:'./src/contact.js'
      },
      ...
    }
    
    module.exports = config;
```

---

**Final thoughts**

Is this method of using `.ejs` files possible with React and Webpack?

Also, I may be really off course, so if there is an easier method of doing this please let me know.

Comment: Have you looked into Gatsby? Or next.js's static build option?

Comment: @WillD I have not, are they both the same? Do they solve the problem I am trying to solve?

Comment: They both allow you build a react-based app and export it to SEO-ready, HTML entry files.

Comment: @WillD So instead of having an html body that only contains, for example `<div id='content'></div>` paired with a javascript file that contains all the content, I would have an html body that actually has the content of my website.

Comment: So I'll tall about Gatsby first. Basically what it does is it creates a build folder full of HTML files that you can deploy to a static web host... each page contains plain HTML of the view that should be served at your various endpoints. But it also contains a link to a bundled javascript react app that will take over after the page is loaded. This means your time to first byte is fast and it also means that google can parse it without any issues, but you get to have you react app too.

Comment: @WillD Does Gatsby replace Webpack?

Comment: @WillD Thanks Gatsby was a big help. I'm coming across a similar issue now on another project that isn't using Gatsby, it's just using `React` and `Webpack` I don't believe there's a way to use gatsby "plain html" feature without switching the whole project to Gatsby. Is there a way to use `next.js` static build option without making the entire project a `next.js` app?